# Closure not working outside of the function scope

Tags: javascript, closures

Just started to learn closures and wrote this code in FireBug:

```
var later;

function outerFunc() {
  var innerVar = "Inside Outer";
  function innerFunc() {
     console.log(innerVar);
  }

  later = innerFunc;
};

outerFunc();
later();
```

But on calling `later();` it returns an undefined value.  Shouldn't it print out `"Inside Outer" ?`

Comment: It does for me: http://jsfiddle.net/sMuNV/ . `console.log` doesn't `return` anything, and your function doesn't `return` anything. Did you really mean to say "return"?

Comment: [`Status: no-repro`](http://jsfiddle.net/ccjAB/)

Comment: When I run it (in Chrome's web inspector) I do get "Inside Outer" (which, to answer your question, is the correct behavior).  The result of that entire expression is `undefined` because there's no return values and the last expression doesn't evaluate to anything.  Are you sure "Inner Outer" isn't being printed as well?

Comment: I checked code and it works... http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/Y3fdV/

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) SO question has some great answers that may help you in the process of learning how closures work.

Comment: well I mean shouldn't it print it TWO times?  one time when I am calling outerFunc... one time when I am calling later() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var later;

function outerFunc() {
  var innerVar = "Inside Outer";
  function innerFunc() {
     console.log(innerVar);
  }

  later = innerFunc;
};

outerFunc(); //Don't run innerFunc, just set later = innerFunc
later(); // Execute innerFunc
```

So it logs it just one time.. It seems nice..

Comment: well I mean shouldn't it print it TWO times? one time when I am calling outerFunc... one time when I am calling later() ?

Comment: @user1899082 no should not, because when you call **outerFunc();** it's just assign name of **function innerFunc** to **later** and that is all. If you want to call it twice you should, instead of ***later = innerFunc;*** do so
***later = innerFunc();***